# Firefox Addon SDK: how can I track exceptions in main.js?

Tags: exception, firefox-addon-sdk

There are a lot of services which collects js exceptions (like qbaka.com). How can I integrate it with my FF extension (especially `main.js`)?

Comment: I'm hoping someone can bring an answer to this too. Since there is no window object on main.js, window.onerror isn't going to cut it. It may be possible, although quite painful, to wrap all your code in a try/catch dispatch function but it will need to be included in every asynchronous block.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to handle all errors - you'll need to do this yourself as far as I know.

Comment: ...I logged this bug, I do think it's a worthwhile idea: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1048704